# Problema con hosting

Tags: ftp, hosting

tengo un problema con un hosting, yo soy el nuevo administrador de este, pero como no se muy bien lo que hizo el anterior, ni donde metió las cosas estoy un poco descolocado, seguro que será un tontería, pero no consigo averiguar que pasa. El tema es que cuando entro a esta URL: http://artesanofood.ca/ carga una imagen en un documento html, que no consigo encontrar... he mirado en inspeccionar elementos de google chrome pero no consigo encontrar ese archivo, para poder modificarlo o más bien, he instalado una plantilla que me ofrecía el hosting, para indicar que la web está en construcción, pero ni instalando la plantilla, se cambia la dichosa página esta, dejo por aquí imagen del árbol de directorios y el contenido de la carpeta public_html

[image: Árbol de directorios y contenido de la carpeta public_html]

Comment: Asegurate primero que el dominio está apuntando al alojamiento que indicas. Actualmente ese dominio apunta a **meganameservers**, es el mismo que tu alojamiento?.

Comment: La URL de la imagen que se ve es esta: http://artesanofood.ca/ESW/Images/default.png , si tu instalación está en `public_html` debería estar en un directorio llamado `ESW` y luego en `Images`.  Pero la instalación puede estar en otra carpeta dentro de `public_html`. Otra cosa que podría estar ocurriendo es una redirección a través de `.htaccess`. La clave es encontrar la carpeta donde tienes instalado tu CMS, que al parecer es Joomla ¿? y revisar si dicha carpeta existe. Yo miraría también los archivos `index`  y `home` para ver que tienen.

Comment: debes verificar los virtualhost creados generalmente estan en la ruta /etc/apache/site-enabled alli encontrara los sitios ; abre el .conf y te saldran las rutas de los sitios y a que dominio pertenece

Comment: @A.Cedano cuando usan un servidor configurados usan virtualhost y por lo general le cambian las rutas depende del sysadmin

Comment: @A.Cedano no tengo en el servidor ninguna carpeta que se llame ESW, e ahí mi problema... que no se a donde está apuntando esto...

Comment: @Jakala estoy mirando lo que me dices, y no es ese el hosting donde está alojado, la empresa dueña de esto, migró el dominio a WHC que es una empresa canadiense...

Comment: @JackNavaRow no tengo ninguna carpeta de apache...

Comment: Creo que está resuelto el tema... es que al migrar el hosting...no se han cambiado los valores de los DNS y por eso aparece aun información del otro hosting...ya he cambiado los valores de los DNS por lo nuevos y en 24h veremos

Comment: Ok. de momento, si quieres, puedes poner en tu archivo hosts una entrada con la ip del servidor y el dominio, y desde tu equipo ver si se ve la pagina web correctamente. Como dices, deben pasar entre 24 y 48h para que se hagan los cambios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final se migró el dominio de hosting y se quitó todo